# Differences between yum update and dnf upgrade

Tags: yum, dnf

I'd like to find out if there are differences between `yum update` and `dnf upgrade`.
I am using CentOS 7. I haven been using BOTH commands at the same time. 
And I just tried it again and this is what happened:

```
yum update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
adobe-linux-x86_64                                       | 2.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
(1/2): adobe-linux-x86_64/primary_db                       | 2.7 kB   00:00     
(2/2): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                         | 6.9 MB   00:02

#############################################################

dnf upgrade

Adobe Systems Incorporated                       15 kB/s | 1.9 kB     00:00    
CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                  45 kB/s | 9.5 MB     03:35    5CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                              2.0 MB/s | 9.4 MB     00:04    
CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                               1.2 MB/s | 929 kB     00:00    
Using metadata from Tue Apr 10 16:22:39 2018
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
```

To me it seems they are showing different updates. But I could be wrong.

Comment: What are you expecting? Neither is offering any new packages to update. They should be the equivalent command. You just went out of your way and installed `dnf` on CentOS before it migrated there from Fedora.

Comment: Thank you Aaron.  One of the reasons that I installed dnf was because I was told that yum is going outdated, and I should start using dnf. Now I have been curious which one actually shows a better updating results. - Denny

Comment: First -- "I haven_'t_ been" or "I have[n] been"?

Comment: Second, `yum` will not go away while CentOS 7 is still current. The earliest you'll see it go away and be superseded by `dnf` is with RHEL8/CentOS8.

Comment: Please read these https://superuser.com/questions/433375/what-is-the-technical-differences-between-update-and-upgrade-with-yum https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211291/yum-vs-dnf-changed-in-fedora-22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first run `update`, then `upgrade`.

Read [Updating Packages from the Command Line with yum](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_network_satellite/5.4/html/reference_guide/sect-reference_guide-package_updater-updating_packages_from_the_command_line_with_yum)

[What is the technical differences between “update” and “upgrade” with yum?](https://superuser.com/questions/433375/what-is-the-technical-differences-between-update-and-upgrade-with-yum)

> **update:**
>
> If run without any packages, update will update every currently installed package. If one or more packages or package globs are
>   specified, Yum will only update the listed packages. While updating
>   packages, yum will ensure that all dependencies are satisfied. […]
>
> If […] the --obsoletes flag is present yum will include package obsoletes in its calculations - this makes it better for
>   distro-version changes, for example: upgrading from somelinux 8.0 to
>   somelinux 9.
>
> **upgrade:**
>
> Is the same as the update command with the --obsoletes flag set.

[In CentOS, what is the difference between yum update and yum upgrade?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/in-centos-what-is-the-difference-between-yum-update-and-yum-upgrade)

[Yum vs DNF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211291/yum-vs-dnf-changed-in-fedora-22)

Compared to Yum, DNF offers:

1. Better dependency management
2. Support Extensions other than Python
3. Documented API
4. Lower memory usage
5. Less automatic synchronization of metadata with repositories, a process that users often complain "happens too often and takes too much time."

See [Will DNF Replace Yum?](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Will-DNF-Replace-Yum)